# Get Html.DropDownList Value in a Controller Function MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get the selected value of a dropdownlist when I click an ActionLink.

[image: See The ActionLink and DropDownLists]

Here is the dropdownlist I am binding from controller.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("resource", new SelectList(ViewBag.ResourceList, ViewBag.SelectedResource), "Resource", new { @class = "span6", @style = "width:14%; color:black;"})
```

And ActionLink with the function without [HttpPost]

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export Data", "ExportData");
```

I have tried from `Request.Form["resource"]` but it gives me null all the time

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            var req = Request.Form["resource"];
        }
```

I just need to get the text value whatever is in the DropDownList inside my ExportData Function.

Comment: DropDownList and Action link should be part of a form and Action link should be submitting the form in order for this to work.

Comment: `ActionLink` is just a link, it doesn't post any values from any form.  It sounds like you meant to create a submit button instead.

Comment: What if I use anchor tag?

Comment: @Zubair: You *are* using an anchor tag.  So I suspect the behavior would be the same if you continue to use an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

The action link basically renders an `a` tag, and the a tag will look something roughly like this;

```
<a href="ExportData">Export Data</a>
```

Because links issue a GET request, any parameters need to be passed via:

```
<a href="ExportData?resource=xyz">Export Data</a>
```

`Request.Form` will always be empty in a get request because a POST request populates the form collection.  But either way, with a GET or POST request, you can pass the data as a parameter of the action method like:

```
public ActionResult ExportData(string resource)
```

So either put a `<form>` around the data you want to post to the server and change the hyperlink to a button to initiate the post, or use javascript to append "?resource=VAL" to the end of the hyperlink HREF attribute, where VAL is the value from the dropdown.

**EDIT**: in the few scenarios I had to do this before, what I'll normally do is on the link, add a data attribute (in C# API, use data_ for data attributes):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export Data", "ExportData", new { data_url = "ExportData" })
```

The reason why I use a data attribute is to preserve the original URL and that way I don't have to do string manipulation.  Using jQuery, on resource value change, you can update the URL easily:

```
$("#resource").on("change", function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var href = $("#linkid").data("url") + "?resource=" + val;
  $("#linkid").attr("href", href);
});
```

Anytime the dropdown changes, it updates the link url.

Comment: And how to replace xyz with the value of the dropdown in the following link?

<a href="ExportData?resource=xyz">Export Data</a>

Comment: OK edited post above with an example of a technique I use

Answer (score -1):

You should try the `GetValues()` method:

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
    var req = Request.Form.GetValues("resource");
}
```

Comment: The `GetValues` method generally can't read values which aren't sent to the server in the first place.